# Tree table command link in child node

Tags: oracle-adf

I have view link that I have dragged it as ADF tree table in .jsff page.

```
        <af:treeTable value="#{bindings.SisaiEndPointView1.treeModel}" var="node"
                rowSelection="single" id="TT1" contentDelivery="immediate"
                columnStretching="last" partialTriggers=":::commandButton1"
                editingMode="clickToEdit"
                contextMenuSelect="true">
    <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
      <af:column id="column1" headerText="Ministry" sortable="true"
                 width="200%">
        <af:outputText value="#{node.Ministry}" id="outputText1"/>            
      </af:column>

    </f:facet>

   <af:column id="column5" headerText="#Errors" width="100%">

 <af:commandLink text="#{node.ErrorMsgCount}" id="cl2" immediate="true"  partialSubmit="true" action="#{pageFlowScope.EndPointBean.testInput}">        

   <af:setActionListener from="test #{node.ErrorMsgCount}"
                              to="#{pageFlowScope.Min}"/>            
 </af:commandLink>


</af:column>
```

```
public String testInput() {
    String str = (String)ADFContext.getCurrent().getPageFlowScope().get("Min");
    System.out.println(str);
    return null;
}
```

I am not getting any value when I am printing in action method STR.
It is comming only hardcoded value "test " but not getting #{node.ErroMsgCount}.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
<af:setPropertyListener from="#{node.ErrorMsgCount}" to="#{pageFlowScope.Min}" type="action"/>
```

Hope it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply I tried property listener also that also not working.

After that i found the solution that the above operation is totally valid. THere was the problem with VO that was not update able.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an actionListener. So, your code will look like:

**Page**

```
<af:treeTable value="#{bindings.SisaiEndPointView1.treeModel}" var="node"
                rowSelection="single" id="TT1" contentDelivery="immediate"
                columnStretching="last" partialTriggers=":::commandButton1"
                editingMode="clickToEdit"
                contextMenuSelect="true">
    <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
      <af:column id="column1" headerText="Ministry" sortable="true"
                 width="200%">
        <af:outputText value="#{node.Ministry}" id="outputText1"/>            
      </af:column>

    </f:facet>

   <af:column id="column5" headerText="#Errors" width="100%">

 <af:commandLink text="#{node.ErrorMsgCount}" id="cl2" immediate="true"  partialSubmit="true" actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.EndPointBean.testInput}">        

   <af:setActionListener from="test #{node.ErrorMsgCount}"
                              to="#{pageFlowScope.Min}"/>            
 </af:commandLink>


</af:column>
```

**Bean**

```
public void testInput(ActionEvent ae) {
    String str = (String)ADFContext.getCurrent().getPageFlowScope().get("Min");
    System.out.println(str);
    return null;
}
```

Few more things.

1. PageFlowScope is for the entire task flow. I am not sure about your use case but use the lowest scope possible.
2. setPropertyListener with type="action" and setActionListener are quite similar, so they will behave the same mostly.
3. This bean that you are using, unless it needs to persist values across pages in a task-flow, lower the scope of the bean from pageFlowScope.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the inmediate="true"

```
<af:commandLink text="#{node.ErrorMsgCount}" id="cl2"  partialSubmit="true" action="#{pageFlowScope.EndPointBean.testInput}">
```

When you set inmediate to true, this skip update model phase and you don't see the changes.

Marcos